# Socket writing not working properly c#

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm working on a biometry system with my C# application.
Sdk provices a connection via TCP/IP on port 2100, and works by receiving and sending strings to communicate .

My class:

```
class Biometry
{
    private System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient _clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();

    public Biometry() {
        //connect to socket
        _clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 2100);
        _clientSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 9000;
    }

    public String identify(String msg) {
        //get network stream
        NetworkStream _serverStream = _clientSocket.GetStream();

        //send an array of bites that represents a string(encoded)
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding ASCII = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
        _serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);


        //reads the response from networkStream
        byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
        _serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)_clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
        string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);

        _serverStream.Close();
        return returndata;

    }
}
```

The problem is:
It is not working!! The biometry only works(SDK only understand my request) when I close the application(connection is closed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to flush the stream before your start reading using `_serverStream.Flush()`.

Another problem might be that in your question you say you need to connect to port 21000, but in your code you connect to 2100, which might be a typo in either place, but should be fixed ;-)

---

In addition to flushing the stream, your server might also be waiting for an "end of message" indicator?

Comment: Sorry, the port was 2100. One thing I notice is that when it executes the socket Write, SDK does not do anything. Flush did not work

Comment: Does the server expect some "end of message" character sequence you're not sending? Maybe it is waiting for more input.

Comment: Yes!! server was waiting a \n, so I sent an Environment.NewLine and it worked!! thank you

Comment: I suggest that if your server only waits for `\n`, you only send `\n`, not any other characters. In addition, please find out whether it also terminates the reply with `\n`. In that case you should rework your receive-code to wait for `\n` instead of simply reading whatever comes in. If you leave your code as it is, you might not get the entire reply!